# How to merge existing python selenium code to RIDE framework

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I have already written my test cases in python selenium. Sample given below

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver

class SprintTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get("http://samplesite.com")
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.driver.maximize_window()

    def test_sample_test_1(self):
        a = self.driver.find_element_by_id('orderId')
        order_no=a.get_attribute('value')
        print order_no
        self.assert(some_condition)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

Now i want to use Robot Framework RIDE for all these cases, but i dont want to write them again. Is there any way to use already written python code to work in RIDE.

Comment: Unfortunately you have to write your tests again. But if you select keywords well, you have good tests even if you have to change system again.

Comment: There is no such thing as "RIDE Framework". RIDE is an IDE, a tool for editing test cases in the robot framework.